# Network Location Awareness Applications for Windows or Mac

Tags: networking, automation

I've heard of applications on Mac that can be used to launch certain programs depending on the Network location.  I'm looking for an application that can accomplish this on Windows or Linux.

One use case is I want to launch synergy with the correct configuration automatically depending on where I am.  And possibly launch certain applications when I get to work or something.

Thanks

Comment: What is the Mac application called?  This might help track down an alternative.

Comment: It's called Marco Polo

Answer (score 1):

The "Network Location Awareness" service (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms739931(VS.85).aspx) in Windows XP (and 2000? I don't recall...) and up will enable this functionality, but I haven't found where anybody has written an application to take advantage of it. I'd love to code something myself, but I don't have enough spare cycles to even begin to think about it.

This wouldn't be a simple little VBScript thing, but it wouldn't be that much coding either. Maybe somebody could pick up the idea and run with it. There's even sample code at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=ef8a6228-f11d-4ba0-b73e-dd8dc7dd11e8&displaylang=en.

There have been numerous times I've wanted this functionality, and I'd think there are more than a few people who would like to see it.